# Difference between kubernates event creationTimestamp and firstTimestamp

Tags: events, kubernetes

when i describe the kubernates events its showing  both creationTimestamp and firstTimestamp, it seems both are same only, What is the exact difference between those timestamps

Answer (score 0):

From [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/master/core/v1/types.go#L5303-L5309):

> **FirstTimestamp**: The time at which the event was first recorded. (Time
> of server receipt is in TypeMeta.)
>
> **LastTimestamp**: The time at which the most recent occurrence of this
> event was recorded.

EDIT:

Both of these fields mentioned above seem to be set by client library: [sourcecode reference](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/62c82f55401c89e85f301733d42caa5570477814/tools/record/event.go#L375)

Note: Not that long time ago [event api change proposal appeared](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-instrumentation/383-new-event-api-ga-graduation/README.md).
This means thet both FirstTimestamp and LastTimestamp are deprecated in favour of EventTime.

---

Event **creationTimestamp** is a field set by api-server during object creation. It's a read only field. [source](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/master/pkg/apis/meta/v1/types.go#L187-L196):

```
// CreationTimestamp is a timestamp representing the server time when this object was
// created. It is not guaranteed to be set in happens-before order across separate operations.
// Clients may not set this value. It is represented in RFC3339 form and is in UTC.
//
// Populated by the system.
// Read-only.
```

Also have a look at the api server [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/7f23a743e8c23ac6489340bbb34fa6f1d392db9d/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/registry/rest/meta.go#L29) for reference to see how its being set.

Comment: Hi , I wanted to know the difference between creationTimestamp and firstTimestamp